# Unable to use Selenium on PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, pythonanywhere

I'm trying to setup a python application that uses Selenium and Chrome on PythonAnywhere. Everything is working in a development environment but I am running into issues when trying to deploy to PythonAnywhere. I'm getting the following traceback when attempting to run the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mattk/Door_Price/main.py", line 51, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/mattk/Door_Price/main.py", line 13, in main
    catalog = Catalog(silent=True)
  File "./driver.py", line 29, in __init__
    self.driver = self._create_engine(path or config.PATH, silent)
  File "./driver.py", line 60, in _create_engine
    driver = Chrome(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 65, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 90, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 177, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, capabilities)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium-browser is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=85.0.4183.87 (cd6713ebf92fa1cacc0f1a598df280093af0c5d7-refs/branch-heads/4183@{#1689}),platform=Linux 5.4.0-1020-aws x86_64)
```

Not sure if PythonAnywhere needs some special configurations?
Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Code causing error:
@staticmethod
def _create_engine(path, silent):
"""Generate Selenium Engine"""

```
    # TODO check if driver is present

    if silent:
        options = ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument('--headless')
        driver = Chrome(
            executable_path=path,
            options=options
        )
    else:
        driver = Chrome(
            executable_path=path
        )

    return driver
```

Comment: Please add the part of the code that is returning the error.

Comment: @Jortega I've added the code

Comment: the error says the issue is coming from here `File "/home/mattk/Door_Price/main.py", line 13, in main
    catalog = Catalog(silent=True)` can you add this part of the code.

Comment: Write to support@pythonanywhere.com to have the required features enabled for your account.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. PythonAnyWhere needed to enable some beta features on the account.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use PythonAnywhere and Selenium on Chrome by default, You need Firefox 17.
Check this: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/selenium/

Comment: You can't do it by default, but you can write to support@pythonanywhere.com to have the required features enabled for your account.

Answer (score 0):

Your submission is somewhat confusing. I think to install on pythonanywhere you need add the "user" flag. Have you tried this?:

```
pip3 install [package] --user
```

In your case:

```
pip3 install selenium --user
```

But from this part of your traceback:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium-browser is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
(Driver info: chromedriver=85.0.4183.87 (cd6713ebf92fa1cacc0f1a598df280093af0c5d7-refs/branch-heads/4183@{#1689}),platform=Linux 5.4.0-1020-aws x86_64)
```

it looks like selenium is already installed.

Comment: Selenium is installed. Does PythonAnywhere require any special configurations to run Selinum with Chrome?

Comment: you're better off asking this in the pythonanywhere forum here: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/